# Como adicionar div antes de outra div com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou com dificuldades de conseguir colocar uma nova div antes de outra ou só adicionar uma div, mas com JavaScript.

Exemplo:

Já tenho uma DIV

```
<div class="primeira"></div>
```

Quero adicionar uma acima dela com Javascript, ficando assim:

```
<div class="div-adicionada"></div>
<div class="primeira"></div>
```

Comment: Lucas, peço que leia este tópico que ensina como criar uma pergunta, ajuda a aumentar as chances de obter respostas úteis, alias Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow BR! http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Se estiver utilizando o jQuery, veja se [isso](http://api.jquery.com/before/) lhe ajuda.

Comment: Da para entender muito bem o que ele quer...

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss 'colocar uma nova DIV antes de outra', obviamente se trata de um 'insertBefore', não vejo motivos em fechar basta pedir mais informações até por que é a primeira pergunta dele.

Comment: Gostaria de um script que crie uma nova DIV acima de outra

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, ta corretíssimo, creio que já foi discutido isso, entre fechar e melhorar a pergunta (mesmo minha opinião sendo comentar). Mas nessa em específico, o que ele tem de melhorar? está mais do que claro.

Comment: Acho que agora da pra entender
Desculpa por não me explicar direito

Comment: O jeito mais fácil de conseguir isso é usando o método insertAdjacentHTML, assim: 

document.getElementsByClassName("primeira")[0].insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<div class='div-adicionada'></div>");

O suporte é muito bom.

Postei aqui até que o tópico esteja aberto a respostas. Depois eu reposto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível usar a função [**`insertAdjacentHTML`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

O primeiro parâmetro é a posição que você quer inserir, use `beforebegin` para adicionar antes. É possível ver [todos os valores possíveis na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

O segundo parâmetro é a *string* HTML que deve ser inserida.

```js
const div = document.getElementsByClassName('primeira')[0];  
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<div class="segunda">Segunda div</div>');
```

```html
<div class="primeira">Primeira div</div>
```

Comment: Esse script de clikar no botão e adicionar eu já achei Estou precisando de um que simplesmente já fique adicionado e uma só vez

Comment: @LucasGiovanni É só colocar isso na inicialização da página.

Comment: @LucasGiovanni Veja minha edição

Comment: @LucasGiovanni Por que removeu a aceitação? Tem algo errado na resposta?

Comment: Acabei tendo um problema aqui agora e já estava pensando como irei lhe explicar

Comment: @LucasGiovanni Ótimo, a gente tá aqui pra se ajudar mesmo. Mas mantenha problemas diferentes em perguntas diferentes, ok? Isso mantém o site organizado e fica muito mais fácil de ajudar outras pessoas e te de ajudar.

Comment: Consegui aqui parceiro, MUITO OBRIGADO!!!

Answer (score 1):

utilize o método `Node.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)`.

```js
var primeira = document.querySelector(".primeira");
var divAdicionada = document.createElement("div");

divAdicionada.classList.add("div_adicionada");
divAdicionada.textContent = "Div Adicionada";

primeira.parentElement.insertBefore(divAdicionada, primeira);
```

```html
<div class="div_qualquer">Div qualquer</div>
<div class="primeira">Primeira</div>
```

Comment: Esse script de clikar no botão e adicionar eu já achei
Estou precisando de um que simplesmente já fique adicionado e uma só vez.